# Atom Class quick delete

Tags: atom-editor

I have an example: (before)

```
.root.rfx-space-between
```

And after:

```
.root
```

Is there any way that I can use only 1 keystroke to delete the '.rfx-space-between' ? Normal Ctrl+Backspace takes at least 3 times to delete the string. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, I rewrote the question :) Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in Atom's preferences, under the "Editor" section, you can define word delimiting characters. These are characters that define the boundary between "word" and "non-word". Plus, of course, whitespace always delimits words.

The default setting is this:

```
/\()"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`?-…
```

If you remove the `-` from this setting (near the end), then will be considered part of a "word", and Ctrl-Backspace would remove `rfx-space-between` in one operation. However, this would leave the trailing dot, and you would end up with

```
.root.
```

You could also remove `.` from that setting if you want. Just keep in mind that this may affect other things. Ctrl-Backspace is not the only operation that takes into account what "word" means to Atom.